# How to find docs for apt installed packages

Tags: documentation

I'm wandering if there is a *universal* way to find docs for apt installed packages, or at least find out *what they do*. Sometimes I run into packages of which I have no idea at all, but I cannot figure out what they do either locally or online.

For instance, what does the package `libaccounts-glib0` do? If it is for web account plugins, I'll simply remove it. If it is for core accounts services, removing it will get me into trouble, I guess. There is not even a one-line description to help me decide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's one of the beauties with FOSS. There isn't a central documentation for every piece of software (that is if the documentation exists in the first place).

Normally when looking for documentation, people rely on the `man` pages, `info` and, if the application is a GUI, the *yelp* help files. That's normally with applications that users can interact with/configure/use directly (the frontend). This includes the `.conf` files, and almost any text configuration file. Then some applications don't do this and rely on the `--help` switch. Ubuntu (and Debian) has a policy for software documentation, that all documentation gets dumped in `/usr/share/doc/packagename`:

```
ls -l /usr/share/doc/ | grep <package_name>
```

So, for the specific case of libraries, some of them includes `-doc`:

> libetsf-io-doc - Developer documentation API and tutorials for ETSF_IO

Or in the specific case of your package `libaccounts-glib0`:

> libaccounts-glib-doc - library for single signon - documentation

For finding this documentation you have to look for the source package `libaccounts-glib`.

Then, there are some packages that don't include the documentation in the repositories for legal reasons, or just don't have any.

In any case, **for finding any documentation**, you should look for the `-doc` of the packages, that normally are suggested (like `ntp` suggest `ntp-doc`), or look for the content of a specific packages to see if it includes some info, man or README file:

```
dpkg -L <package> | grep -P '/man|info|README|doc/'
```

Comment: Also have a look at `/usr/share/doc/packagename` - this is the location of the documentation as per the Debian/Ubuntu packaging guidelines.